# How to scrape synopsis from IMDb in Spanish?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, imdb

I am trying to scrape a movie title and its synopsis in Spanish. Although both of them are shown in Spanish on the website, after scraping the page using BeautifulSoup I get the title in Spanish but the movie description in English. I know there is a way of using Accept-Language for headers in order to be able to change the language, but I am not aware of such or similar thing for bodies.

My code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038650/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1'
result = requests.get(website)
content = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

box = soup.find('section', class_='ipc-page-section ipc-page-section--baseAlt ipc-page-section--tp-xs ipc-page-section--bp-xs Hero__HeroParent-kvkd64-1 fARFJI')
title = box.find('h1', class_ = 'TitleHeader__TitleText-sc-1wu6n3d-0 dxSWFG').get_text()
synopsis = box.find('span', class_='GenresAndPlot__TextContainerBreakpointXL-cum89p-2 gCtawA').get_text()
print(title)
print(synopsis)
```

And the output is

> ¡Qué bello es vivir!

> An angel is sent from Heaven to help a desperately frustrated businessman by showing him what life would have been like if he had never existed.

Comment: By default IMDb users see titles listed in the language used for release in their country (i.e. US-based users will see films listed under the title used for the North American release, while users browsing the site from France will see titles as they appeared on the French release of those movies etc.)

Comment: yes, I know that. my question is why do I get it in English while I see it in Spanish on the web? and how actually I can get it in Spanish then? @baduker